# Declension after -selbe words (Im denselben/In demselben/im demselben) with article

Tags: declension

Consider

> 1. in **the** same year  *or*
> 2. in **the** same sense,

both of which contain the article. Suppose also, that the context needs dative. I want to use a `x`*-selbe* word to express this in German.

**Question: where to put the article?**

(a) The article is absorbed by the `x`*-selbe* word, being this *demselben*
(b) The article is contracted with the prepostion *in*
(c) The article is contracted with the preposition, and `x`=*dem* just because it should be dative

> **1a**. In demselben Jahr *or* **1b**. Im denselben Jahr   *or* **1c.** Im demselben Jahr
>   **2a**. In demselben Sinn(e) *or* **2b**. Im denselben Sinn(e)
>   *or* **2c.** Im demselben Sinn(e)

I mean, following the rules it should be (c). But then it seems funny

> **Im dem**...

like, even though *dem-* just refers to the declension in the table, I've not aware of having seen two *-m* endings together.

Comment: Neither ;) – "Dergleiche" does not exist. "Dergleichen", though, but that's something different. "Derselbe" is also a different. What you're looking for is "in dem gleichen/selben Jahr" or "im gleichen/selben Jahr"

Answer (score 3):

The usual expression is *im selben Jahr*, i.e. the article contained in *derselbe* is absorbed by the preposition in the normal way. The same is true for other relevant prepositions (*am selben Ort*, *zur selben Zeit*) and for the accusative (*ins selbe Zimmer*).

It is possible to keep preposition and article separated for emphasis or rhythm (*in demselben Jahr*); this is in no way specific to *derselbe*, though (*in dem Jahr*).

In short, *derselbe* behaves exactly like *der gleiche*. The difference is just the spelling.

Comment: Should I use *in **dem**selben Jahr* for demostrative *dem* (instead of just a dull article?)

Comment: @c.p. Yes: _X wurde in demselben Jahr geboren, in dem Y verstarb._

Comment: @c.p. _in demselben jahr_ would put extra emphasis on the fact that it is _really that selfsame year!_